# Make grid collapse/stack sooner in Bootstrap 3.1

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was able to make the navbar collapse sooner using the CSS code from http://www.bootply.com/120604
How do I make the grid collapse or stack into 1 column sooner?

I only have two columns: col-sm-3 and col-sm-9. The responsive design works fine on mobile, but I would like to achieve the same behavior on tablets (768px to 991px).

I have to use Bootstrap CDN, so my only option is to override the default using CSS. Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't using the `md` grid size work for you? http://www.bootply.com/egOwqBFJBu

Comment: Yes, and thanks! Just shows how foreign bootstrap is still for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to override the css, just use `md` in your col-*-# classes instead of `sm`. i.e.

```
<div class="col-md-3">Stuff</div>
<div class="col-md-9">More Stuff</div>
```

Then go to the bar, because you're done!

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna go to the bar now :)